# PHP memcache not closing connections?

Tags: php, memcached

I am using [PHP-memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) on various web servers to connect memcache servers.

I connect like this:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host', 11211);
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host2', 11211);
```

Then fetch or set the data using `get & set`.

It works fine in most of the case but if something goes slow down then i see a sudden increase in memcache connections, which will create issues.

I think this is because by default `addServer` creates persistent connections & may be not closing them quickly after serving the request.

A similar issue has been reported [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/memcached@lists.danga.com/msg02683.html) also.

So please let me know is this only because of default behavior of `addServer` function. Should i use non-persistent connection by passing `false` as third argument in `addServer` function.

Comment: tcp keep alive is probably set high to a high number of seconds. this has nothing to with PHP. don't trust the mecmached stats. look at `netstat`

Comment: @true i checked my netstat -nat & i can see so many ESTABLISHED connection, in normal case the number is around 13000 but when slow down happens they got increased to 23000. Also no connection is in TIME_WAIT state.my tcp_keepalive_time is 600.

Answer (score 0):

Because memcached open connections might be kept by the kernel in keepalive mode if not explicitely closed by the client, lowering the following parameters might help, but will affect any other connection, like SSH. So putting tcp_keepalive_time too low is not a good idea.
Create the following file :

```
vim /etc/sysctl.d/low-tcp-timeout.conf

# Keep connections in keepalive for 600 seconds. Default 7200s = 2h.
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
# 0 probes. Default 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 0
# Default 75 seconds between each probe
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
```

and run `sysctl -p` to apply these values.
You can also have a look at `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`